# shell scripting "test " command

Tags: linux, shell

I m writing shell program to compare two numbers and show the status using test command

```
#!/bin/sh
a="42"
b="23"
echo $a
test [$a -eq $b]
echo $?
```

but I m getting error like this
 eq: line 5: test: [42: integer expression expected 2

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change line

```
test [$a -eq $b]
```

to

```
test $a -eq $b
```

test expects an integer expression and [$a -eq $b] is not an integer experssion

Comment: and maybe a few explanatory words ... ?  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Loose the square brackets.  from

```
test [$a -eq $b]
```

Where line should be

```
test $a -eq $b
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use below simplified answer**

```
#!/bin/sh
a=42
b=23
echo $a
test $a -eq $b
echo $?
```

It will print answer as ***1*** since ***a*** is not equal to ***b***

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the square brackets.

From the manual pages, you use the square brackets as an alternate to explicitly using the "test" word. So it is one or the other.

From the [man](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html) page:

```
test Evaluate a conditional expression expr. Syntax
      test expr
         [ expr ]
        [[ expr ]] [ is a synonym for test but requires a final argument of ].
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `man test` and in the manual page you will see that it expects your expression after `test`. Your expression being `$a -eq $b`, the command should be `test $a -eq $b`

What you are doing wrong:

1. Using square brackets is as same as the test. Try `man [` and you will be directed to the same manual page as `man test`. You are trying to use both
2. Since `[` itself is a command, you need a space after `[` before the next part of the command. Therefore it should be `[ $a -eq $b ]` instead of `[$a -eq $b]`

In the line where you have used `test [$a -eq $b]`, you can use either

1. `test $a -eq $b` or
2. `[ $a -eq $b ]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one because they are the same (regardless of some shell builtins)

```
$ ls -l /bin/{test,[}
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  22704  4 May 00:05 /bin/[
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  22704  4 May 00:05 /bin/test
```

so either

```
test expr
```

or

```
[ expr ]
```

or even

```
/bin/[ expr ]
```